# Superfish mouseout delay not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, superfish

On my client's site: http://mural.planet-9-stuff.co.uk/ (in final stages before going live) I've got JS menus that seem to be using the Superfish code. 
Problem is, when you try to navigate from Services > For individuals to one of the 'for individuals' sub-pages (particularly one that's diagonally down & to the right of the 'For individuals' header, like "Investing for children" for example), the menu disappears and it's really annoying.

I've adjusted the Superfish config settings to give a delay of 10000, disableHI etc but none of it seems to be taking effect. I've also adjusted various settings in my screen.css file but again, nothing is giving me the result I want.

Here's the superfish code:

```
/* Dropdown menu using superfish */
    jQuery('.nav').supersubs({
        minWidth: 12,
        maxWidth: 25,
        extraWidth: 1
    }).superfish({
        delay: 10000,
        animation: {opacity: 'show', height: 'show' },
        speed: 'slow',
        autoArrows: false,
        disableHI: true
    });
```

I'm a total JS novice so any simple instructions anyone could share would be really gratefully received!